# When classes in shared depend on separate JVM and JS implementations of classes in Scala.js?

Tags: intellij-idea, cross-platform, scala.js

Please consider a cross compiled scala.js library that depends on a class called Core.

Core requires separate JVM and JS implementations because it relies on native features.

Remember that the cross compiled directory structure for scala.js includes a js folder for javascript only code, a jvm folder for JVM only code, and a shared folder for code that pertains to both environments.

The problem is that the bulk of the library occupies the shared context, but depends on the Core class.  Unfortunately, intelliJ does not link references to Core from the shared context and this impedes progress.

In other situations, I've abstracted method signatures into traits and referred to the traits instead of the implementing classes, but in this case the shared code invokes a lot of constructors and factories directly.

Is there a design trick or a way to configure intelliJ so that shared code can reference implementation specific classes?

Comment: Seems there is common issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12945.

Comment: Thanks!  Know any creative or workarounds?

Comment: @BenMcKenneby Sounds interesting - can you share an example project. I have no idea how this should work;( - also not with SBT.

Comment: @pme.  Check out the Img class in this project: https://github.com/dragonfly-ai/img from the perspective of ImgOps.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always the client and the server module that depend on the shared module in a Crossproject.

So this is how I would try to do this:

Put the Core classes to a Library (yet another Cross-Project).

Then you can add its distributions as dependencies:

- the JVM lib to jvm-Project
- the JS lib to js-Project

This should also work fine in Intellij.

Comment: That is something to try!  Will get back to you.